# Iterate inner objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Here is my JSON object:

```
{
"id": 2,
"full_name": "Karan Kumar",
"user_skills": [
   {
      "skill_id": 1,
      "skill": {
          "skill_name": "Angular 8"
       }
   },
   {
      "skill_id": 3,
      "skill": {
          "skill_name": "Java Spring"
       }
    }
],
"resource_allocateds": [
  {
     "project_id": 1,
     "end_date": "2019-06-20",
     "project": {
         "project_name": "Inventory System"
      }
  },
  {
      "project_id": 2,
      "end_date": "2020-01-15",
      "project": {
           "project_name": "Hospital Management System"
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to pick certain properties from the above JSON and I want to have it something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "full_name": "Karan Kumar",
    "skills": [{
        "skill_id": 1,
        "skill_name": "Angular 8"
    },
    {
        "skill_id": 3,
       "skill_name": "Java Spring"
    }],
    "resource_allocateds": [{
        "project_id": 1,
        "end_date": "2019-06-20",
        "project_name": "Inventory System"
    },
    {
        "project_id": 2,
        "end_date": "2020-01-15",
        "project_name": "Hospital Management System"
    }]
}
```

I tried using Lodash's `partialRight`, but it seems it doesn't work on iterable objects and also tried flatMap, but didn't work. It would be great if somebody helps me to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vanilla javascript instead of Lodash to do that. Look for ES6 methods like map/reduce/filter. Example :

```
const input = {
"id": 2,
"full_name": "Karan Kumar",
"user_skills": [
   {
      "skill_id": 1,
      "skill": {
          "skill_name": "Angular 8"
       }
   },
   {
      "skill_id": 3,
      "skill": {
          "skill_name": "Java Spring"
       }
    }
],
"resource_allocateds": [
  {
     "project_id": 1,
     "end_date": "2019-06-20",
     "project": {
         "project_name": "Inventory System"
      }
  },
  {
      "project_id": 2,
      "end_date": "2020-01-15",
      "project": {
           "project_name": "Hospital Management System"
       }
    }
  ]
};

const { id, full_name, user_skills, resource_allocateds } = input;

const output = {
  id,
  full_name,
  skills: user_skills.map(item => ({
      skill_id: item.skill_id,
      skill_name: item.skill.skill_name
    })),
  resource_allocateds: resource_allocateds.map(item => ({
      project_id: item.project_id,
      end_date: item.end_date,
      project_name: item.project.project_name
    })),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toArray` and `mapValues` like shown below:

```js
const jsonData = {
  "id": 2,
  "full_name": "Karan Kumar",
  "user_skills": [
     {
        "skill_id": 1,
        "skill": {
            "skill_name": "Angular 8"
         }
     },
     {
        "skill_id": 3,
        "skill": {
            "skill_name": "Java Spring"
         }
      }
  ],
  "resource_allocateds": [
    {
       "project_id": 1,
       "end_date": "2019-06-20",
       "project": {
           "project_name": "Inventory System"
        }
    },
    {
        "project_id": 2,
        "end_date": "2020-01-15",
        "project": {
             "project_name": "Hospital Management System"
         }
    }
  ]
};

const transformedJson = {...jsonData};
transformedJson.user_skills = _.toArray(_.mapValues(transformedJson.user_skills, ({ skill_id, skill }) => {
  return {
    skill_id,
    skill_name: skill.skill_name
  };
}));
transformedJson.resource_allocateds = _.toArray(_.mapValues(transformedJson.resource_allocateds, ({ project_id, project }) => {
  return {
    project_id,
    project_name: project.project_name
  };
}));

document.getElementById('jsonResults').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(transformedJson, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="jsonResults"></pre>
```